# Insert into database c# connection string error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i am encountering an error when trying to set up an insert command into my database, it appears to be with the connection string. I am extremely new to all this and am trying to get the correct code in order to upload into my database and assume that the syntax i am using may be wrong and the cause of the error.

Here is the code a little bit clearer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ComputingProjectwh.TestPages._1._Further_Mechanics
{
    public partial class Moments_and_Energy_Test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsValid)
                return;
            int score = 0;
            List<RadioButtonList> list = new List<RadioButtonList>() { RadioButtonList1, RadioButtonList2, RadioButtonList3, RadioButtonList4, RadioButtonList5, RadioButtonList6, RadioButtonList7, RadioButtonList8, RadioButtonList9, RadioButtonList10 };
            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                if (element.SelectedValue == "Correct")
                {
                    score++;
                }

            }
            Response.Write("you scored: " + score);
            Button1.Visible = false;

            if (score != 0);
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246.mdf;InitialCatalog=aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246;IntegratedSecurity=True");

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT AspNetUserTestScores (Id, MomentAndEnergyTestScore) VALUES (Id, score)";
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                sqlConnection1.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection1.Close();


            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I am really not sure what the problem is and cant seem to find an answer on the internet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Refer https://www.connectionstrings.com for correct connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to MSSQL, there is no `initialcatalog`, You are using a wrong connection string.

This is the correct syntax:

```
  Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Or in your case, for trusted connection:

```
  Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

With your data:

```
 SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=LocalDb;Database=aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

Comment: It doesnt recognise anything in those strings?

Comment: like this? `SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(Server= LocalDb; Database= aspnet - ComputingProjectwh - 20170404101246.mdf; Trusted_Connection = True;);`

Comment: I think that my connection string is correct but the actual data ive put in is wrong now as im getting an error saying that connection could not be established. is that the correct syntax when connecting to a local server created by asp itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141280/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-daniel-turville).

Comment: Sorry new to this, how do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

`InitialCatalog` is two separate words `initial catalog`.

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference for me. I assume my syntax is wrong or old

Comment: Please see my answer